# How to disable the file system redirection within a powershell script

Tags: windows

On x64 windows platforms, how can i disable the file system redirection within a powershell script.

About the file system redirection, refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why would you? "32-bit applications can access the native system directory by substituting %windir%\Sysnative for %windir%\System32."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this should be an answer. Out of dozens of similar questions here, your comment was the first to mention this folder.